# TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found text analytics

Tags: python

I'm trying to analyze a group of 4 documents. I've read all 4 documents into a corpus as a list with 4 element (one for each document). I'm trying to write a function to clean the corpus (change case to lowercase, remove stop words, remove punctuation, and split into words). I was able to remove stopwords and punctuation but have issues splitting the sentences into words.

Below is my code

```
# stop words
stop = set(stopwords.words('english'))

# punctuation
exclude = set(string.punctuation)

# lemmatization
lemma = WordNetLemmatizer()

# Function that preprocesses the corpus
def clean(text):
    # converting text into all lowercase 
    lower_case = "".join([i.lower() for i in text if i.lower() not in stop])
    # remove stop words
    remove_stop = ''.join(char for char in lower_case if char not in exclude)
    # remove punctuations and normalize text
    normalized = "".join(lemma.lemmatize(word) for word in remove_stop.split())
    return normalized 

# Create a new processed corpus
prepocessed_corpus = [clean(doc).split() for doc in corpus]

print(prepocessed_corpus)
```

This is the output I get.

[['adsaleboosttimewarnerprofitquarterlyprofitatumediumgianttimewarnerjumped76to113bn£600mforthethreemonthtodecemberfrom639myearearlierthefirmwhichisnowoneofthebiggestinvestoringooglebenefitedfromsaleofhighspeedinternetconnectionandhigheradvertsaletimewarnersaidfourthquartersalerose2to111bnfrom109bnitprofitwerebuoyedbyoneoffgainwhichoffsetaprofitdipatwarnerbrosandleuserforaoltimewarnersaidonfridaythatitnowowns8ofsearchenginegooglebutitowninternetbusinessaolhadhamixedfortuneitlost464000subscriberinthefourthquarterprofitwerelowerthanintheprecedingthreequarterhoweverthecompanysaidaolsunderlyingprofitbeforeexceptionalitemrose8onthebackofstrongerinternetadvertisingrevenueithopetoincreasesubscriberbyofferingtheonlineservicefreetotimewarnerinternetcustomerandwilltrytosignupaolsexistingcustomerforhighspeedbroadbandtimewarneralsohatorestate2000and2003resultfollowingaprobebytheusecurityexchangecommissionsecwhichisclosetoconcludingtimewarnerfourthquarterprofitwereslightlybetterthananalystexpectationbutitfilmdivisionsawprofitslump27to284mhelpedbyboxofficeflopalexanderandcatwomanasharpcontrasttoyearearlierwhenthethirdandfinalfilminthelordoftheringtrilogyboostedresultforthefullyeartimewarnerpostedaprofitof336bnup27fromit2003performancewhilerevenuegrew64to4209bnourfinancialperformancewastrongmeetingorexceedingallofourfullyearobjectiveandgreatlyenhancingourflexibilitychairmanandchiefexecutiverichardparsonsaidfor2005timewarnerisprojectingoperatingearningsgrowthofaround5andalsoexpectshigherrevenueandwiderprofitmargintimewarneristorestateitaccountapartofefforttoresolveaninquiryintoaolbyumarketregulatorithaalreadyofferedtopay300mtosettlechargeinadealthatisunderreviewbythesecthecompanysaiditwaunabletoestimatetheamountitneededtosetasideforlegalreservewhichitpreviouslysetat500mitintendstoadjustthewayitaccountforadealwithgermanmusicpublisherbertelsmannspurchaseofastakeinaoleuropewhichithadreportedaadvertisingrevenueitwillnowbookthesaleofitstakeinaoleuropeaalossonthevalueofthatstake'], ['dollargainongreenspanspeechthedollarhahitithighestlevelagainsttheeuroinalmostthreemonthafterthefederalreserveheadsaidtheutradedeficitissettostabiliseandalangreenspanhighlightedtheugovernmentwillingnesstocurbspendingandrisinghouseholdsavingafactorwhichmayhelptoreduceitinlatetradinginnewyorkthedollarreached12871againsttheeurofrom12974onthursdaymarketconcernaboutthedeficithahitthegreenbackinrecentmonthonfridayfederalreservechairmanmrgreenspansspeechinlondonaheadofthemeetingofg7financeministersentthedollarhigherafterithadearliertumbledonthebackofworsethanexpectedujobdataithinkthechairmantakingamuchmoresanguineviewonthecurrentaccountdeficitthanhetakenforsometimesaidrobertsincheheadofcurrencystrategyatbankofamericainnewyorkhetakingalongertermviewlayingoutasetofconditionunderwhichthecurrentaccountdeficitcanimprovethisyearandnextworryaboutthedeficitconcernaboutchinadohoweverremainchinacurrencyremainspeggedtothedollarandtheucurrencysharpfallinrecentmonthhavethereforemadechineseexportpricehighlycompetitivebutcallforashiftinbeijingpolicyhavefallenondeafeardespiterecentcommentinamajorchinesenewspaperthatthetimeisripeforalooseningofthepegtheg7meetingisthoughtunlikelytoproduceanymeaningfulmovementinchinesepolicyinthemeantimetheufederalreservedecisionon2februarytoboostinterestratebyaquarterofapointthesixthsuchmoveinamanymonthhaopenedupadifferentialwitheuropeanratethehalfpointwindowsomebelievecouldbeenoughtokeepuassetlookingmoreattractiveandcouldhelppropupthedollartherecentfallhavepartlybeentheresultofbigbudgetdeficitawellatheusyawningcurrentaccountgapbothofwhichneedtobefundedbythebuyingofubondandassetbyforeignfirmandgovernmentthewhitehousewillannounceitbudgetonmondayandmanycommentatorbelievethedeficitwillremainatclosetohalfatrilliondollar'], ['yukosunitbuyerfaceloanclaimtheownerofembattledrussianoilgiantyukosaretoaskthebuyerofitformerproductionunittopaybacka900m£479mloanstateownedrosneftboughttheyuganskunitfor93bninasaleforcedbyrussiatopartsettlea275bntaxclaimagainstyukosyukosownermenatepgroupsayitwillaskrosnefttorepayaloanthatyuganskhadsecuredonitassetrosneftalreadyfaceasimilar540mrepaymentdemandfromforeignbanklegalexpertsaidrosneftspurchaseofyuganskwouldincludesuchobligationthepledgedassetarewithrosneftsoitwillhavetopayrealmoneytothecreditortoavoidseizureofyuganskassetsaidmoscowbasedulawyerjamiefirestonewhoisnotconnectedtothecasemenatepgroupmanagingdirectortimosbornetoldthereutersnewsagencyiftheydefaultwewillfightthemwheretheruleoflawexistsundertheinternationalarbitrationclauseofthecreditrosneftofficialwereunavailableforcommentbutthecompanyhasaiditintendstotakeactionagainstmenateptorecoversomeofthetaxclaimanddebtowedbyyuganskyukoshadfiledforbankruptcyprotectioninaucourtinanattempttopreventtheforcedsaleofitmainproductionarmthesalewentaheadindecemberandyuganskwasoldtoalittleknownshellcompanywhichinturnwaboughtbyrosneftyukosclaimitdownfallwapunishmentforthepoliticalambitionofitfoundermikhailkhodorkovskyandhavowedtosueanyparticipantinthesale'], ['highfuelpricehitbaprofitbritishairwayhablamedhighfuelpricefora40dropinprofitreportingitresultforthethreemonthto31december2004theairlinemadeapretaxprofitof£75m141mcomparedwith£125mayearearlierrodeddingtonbachiefexecutivesaidtheresultwererespectableinathirdquarterwhenfuelcostroseby£106mor473baprofitwerestillbetterthanmarketexpectationof£59manditexpectsariseinfullyearrevenuetohelpoffsettheincreasedpriceofaviationfuelbalastyearintroducedafuelsurchargeforpassengerinoctoberitincreasedthisfrom£6to£10onewayforalllonghaulflightwhiletheshorthaulsurchargewaraisedfrom£250to£4alegyetaviationanalystmikepowellofdresdnerkleinwortwassersteinsaybaestimatedannualsurchargerevenue£160mwillstillbewayshortofitadditionalfuelcostapredictedextra£250mturnoverforthequarterwaup43to£197bnfurtherbenefitingfromariseincargorevenuelookingaheadtoitfullyearresulttomarch2005bawarnedthatyieldaveragerevenueperpassengerwereexpectedtodeclineaitcontinuestolowerpriceinthefaceofcompetitionfromlowcostcarrierhoweveritsaidsalewouldbebetterthanpreviouslyforecastfortheyeartomarch2005thetotalrevenueoutlookisslightlybetterthanpreviousguidancewitha3to35improvementanticipatedbachairmanmartinbroughtonsaidbahadpreviouslyforecasta2to3riseinfullyearrevenueitalsoreportedonfridaythatpassengernumberrose81injanuaryaviationanalystnickvandenbrulofbnpparibasdescribedbalatestquarterlyresultaprettymodestitisquitegoodontherevenuesideanditshowtheimpactoffuelsurchargeandapositivecargodevelopmenthoweveroperatingmargindownandcostimpactoffuelareverystronghesaidsincethe11september2001attackintheunitedstatebahacut13000jobapartofamajorcostcuttingdriveourfocusremainsonreducingcontrollablecostanddebtwhilstcontinuingtoinvestinourproductmreddingtonsaidforexamplewehavetakendeliveryofsixairbusa321aircraftandnextmonthwewillstartfurtherimprovementtoourclubworldflatbedbashareclosedupfourpennyat2745penny']]

I keep trying to implement .split() when converting to lowercase such as this

```
# Function that preprocesses the corpus
def clean(text):
    # converting text into all lowercase 
    lower_case = "".join([i.lower().split() for i in text if i.lower() not in stop])
    # remove remove stop words
    remove_stop = ''.join(char for char in lower_case if char not in exclude)
    # remove punctuations and normalize text
    normalized = "".join(lemma.lemmatize(word) for word in remove_stop.split())
    return normalized
```

However, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_20096/3498144605.py in <module>
     19 
     20 # Create a new processed corpus
---> 21 prepocessed_corpus = [clean(doc).split() for doc in corpus]
     22 
     23 print(prepocessed_corpus)

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_20096/3498144605.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     19 
     20 # Create a new processed corpus
---> 21 prepocessed_corpus = [clean(doc).split() for doc in corpus]
     22 
     23 print(prepocessed_corpus)

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_20096/3498144605.py in clean(text)
     11 def clean(text):
     12     # converting text into all lowercase
---> 13     lower_case = "".join([i.lower().split() for i in text if i.lower() not in stop])
     14     # remove remove stop words
     15     remove_stop = ''.join(char for char in lower_case if char not in exclude)

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found
```

Comment: Show us the full traceback, not just the error message. Don't make us guess which line is causing the error. And don't put it in a comment. [Edit] your question.

Comment: When you split a string, you get a list. Since you do this inside a list comprehension, you get a list of list. You then join that list of lists, but you can only join a list (or any iterable) of strings. So what you are trying to do, doesn't make sense.

Comment: It's unclear why you want to split the individual parts. Do you want to separate words by e.g., a space, or do you indeed want to create an inner lists with individual words? In that case, you can't (and shouldn't) join them, since that defeats the idea of keeping a nested list.

Comment: @BoarGules Sorry about that. I edited my question to include the full traceback.

Comment: @9769953 What I want is a list of 4 lists where each of the 4 lists is a list of all the words in the given document.

Comment: You already get that, if you remove the `"".join` part. The next list comprehensions will be a bit different then, but if you don't join the first list comprehension, and print out the intermediate result (`lower_case`), you should see a list of 4 lists, each with a list of words.

Comment: @9769953 Ah I see! Thank you!